# Regex first and last characters must be a number

Tags: regex

Could you please help me come up with a correct regex to match a string that starts and ends with a digit. The string between these two digits may have `,` and `.` and digits only.

I have tried:

```
([0-9.,]+)
```

Strings to match:

```
,5,190
,5,190,
```

Output should be `5,190`.

Comment: `^[0-9][0-9.,]*[0-9]$`

Comment: `^\d[\d,.]*\d$`

Comment: The question is confusing, "regex to match string starting and end with number" Sample input: ,5,190 ,5,190, Output should be 5,190 But for none of the input starts with number therefore there shouldn't be any output . isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright let's take your definition bit by bit:

- string starting with a number.

  `[0-9]` or `\d` same thing.
- String may have , and . and consist only from numbers.

  `[\d,.]*
- string ends with a number.

  `\d`

Which gives you `\d[\d,.]*\d`. Try it, and please try to understand it before moving on.

Comment: The question is confusing, "regex to match string starting and end with number"  Sample input:  ,5,190
,5,190,

Output should be 5,190             But for none of the input starts with number therefore there shouldn't be any output . isn't it ?

Comment: True dat. I think it's an English problem. I don't think the OP means ^....$, rather find the first `\d` then some shit then stop after the last `\d`. But then again, I'm trying to read minds, failing, and just applying my judgment ;-)